# Passing two different classes for single jaxb instance

Tags: java, jaxb, singleton, marshalling, unmarshalling

Below is my singleton class which creates jaxb instance.
I am using `contextObject` for marshalling and unmarshalling. But in both cases I have different .class (`Class abc` in my code). Problem is `contextObj` will be created only once for only one class lets say for marshalling. But I am using another .class for unmarshalling. Then how can I do this in this code? Thanks

```
public class JAXBInitialisedSingleton {

    private static JAXBContext contextObj = null;

    private JAXBInitialisedSingleton() {

    }

    public static JAXBContext getInstance(Class abc) {
        try {
            if (contextObj == null) {
                contextObj = JAXBContext.newInstance(abc);
            }
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to initialise");
        }
        return contextObj;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have already noticed that the single object `JAXBContext contextObj`
is not enough.

Instead you need a [`Map<Class, JAXBContext>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) mapping from `Class` objects to `JAXBContext` objects.

You need to reorganize your `getInstance(Class)` method a little bit.
Only 3 lines (marked with `//!!`) need to be changed.
In the `Map` you keep all the `JAXBContext` objects created so far.
Whenever you need a `JAXBContext` which was already created earlier,
you find it in the `Map` and can reuse it.

```
public class JAXBInitialisedSingleton {

    private static Map<Class, JAXBContext> contextMap = new HashMap<>();  //!!

    private JAXBInitialisedSingleton() {
    }

    public static JAXBContext getInstance(Class abc) {
        JAXBContext contextObj = contextMap.get(abc);        //!!
        try {
            if (contextObj == null) {
                contextObj = JAXBContext.newInstance(abc);
                contextMap.put(abc, contextObj);             //!!
            }
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to initialise");
        }
        return contextObj;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
## You can try like below -##


public final class JAXBContextConfig
{
    private JAXBContextConfig()
    {
    }

    public static final JAXBContext JAXB_CONTEXT_REQ;

    public static final JAXBContext JAXB_CONTEXT_RES;


    static
    {
        try
        {
            JAXB_CONTEXT_REQ = JAXBContext.newInstance(Request.class);
            JAXB_CONTEXT_RES = JAXBContext.newInstance(Response.class);

        }
        catch (JAXBException e)
        {
            throw new ManhRestRuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

}
```